# change width of a div on the fly, setting with $('#contentDiv').width(newWidth) does not work

Tags: jquery, resize, width, resizable

I have 3 divs arrranged like -

```
    --------------------------
    |  f      |  headlineDiv  |
    |  i      |               |<- draggable and resizable
    |  l      |_______________|
    |  t      |               |
    |  e      |               |<- draggable and resizable
    |  r div  |  storyDiv     |
    |--------------------------
        ^
        |
    can be hidden
```

Heres some code :

```
 <div id="main">
    <div id="showFiltersDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="filtersDiv">
        <div id="hideTextDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentDiv">
        <div id="headlineDiv">
            Block 1</div>
        <div id="storyDiv">
            Block 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

heres the jquery code:
for Resize ->

```
            $('#headlineDiv').resize(function () {
            var offset = $('#headlineDiv').position();
            var height = $('#headlineDiv').height();
            var width = $('#contentDiv').width();
            var top = offset.top + height + "px";
            var newStoryHeight = $("#main").height() - $("#headlineDiv").height();
            var maxHeight = $("#main").height();

             $('#storyDiv').css({
                'bottom': 0,
                'height': newStoryHeight,
                'top': top,
                'position': 'absolute',
                'width': width
            });

            $('#headlineDiv').css({
                'max-height': maxHeight,
                'width': width
            });
        });
```

The code for #storyDiv is similar

Heres the code that should make them expand to fit the extra space -

```
             $('#showFiltersDiv').click(function () {
            $('#filtersDiv, #hideTextDiv').show("slide", { direction: "left" });
            $('#showFiltersDiv').hide();
            var left_margin = $('#filtersDiv').width();
            var perm_width = $('#main').width() - left_margin;               
            var storyTop = $('#storyDiv').position().top;
            $('#headlineDiv').width(perm_width);
            $('#headlineDiv').css({
                'float': 'right',
                'left': $('#main').width() - perm_width,
                'position': 'absolute'
                //'width': perm_width
            });

            $('#storyDiv').css({
                'float': 'right',
                'left': $('#main').width() - perm_width,
                'position': 'absolute',
                'width': perm_width
            });
        });
```

when headlineDiv is resized, storyDiv should adjust its height accordingly. Their positions are interchangeable. So if the user drags `storyDiv` above, `headlineDiv` will be placed below it. Hence, then if `storyDiv` is resized, `headlineDiv` will adjust it's height accordingly. For some reason, when the user tries to resize either, their width decreases by around 10px. To fix this, i set the width of these divs to be equal to their parent in the resize function.

Now, `filterDiv` is a toggle `div`. So when a user hides it, `headlineDiv` and `storyDiv` should expand on the left and occupy the new space. To do that, I'm changing their width. However, setting the width with `$('#headlineDiv ').width(newWidth)` has no effect. Any suggestions on what could do the trick?

Comment: Pictures are nice but some code would be helpful as well.

Comment: How are you toggling your div? Visibility or Display? Also in your diagram you label them `headlineDiv`, `storyDiv` and `filerDiv`, but in your description you call them `div1` `div2` and `div3`. It's a little vague

Comment: Changed the question as per above comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery UI resizeable. It has options for "alsoResize" built right in. Since rules you are providing aren't clear you can write a simple function in "alsoResize" yourself

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Comment: I have used resizable. However, since i'm setting the width explicitly in the resize() function, it does not have the desired effect.

Comment: post a demo then on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I found some mistakes in my css, and so am re-writing some logic. As per your advise, im trying to first use resizable to achieve this. However, 2 divs that are horizontally side by side both try to expand into each other. heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyS4f/